# Can your iOS app use speech/voice recognition even when the app isn't running and the iPhone is locked?

Tags: ios, speech-recognition

The app would be using Speech API and not SiriKit since Siri requires "Hey Siri" to be activated before it can take any input. 
I want my app to be always listening and call a function when the user says a certain word. Is it possible to have this feature in the app?

Answer (score 0):

Your app can run in background only in certain scenarios. For further details, see [this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

Your application seems to fit in the `Apps that record audio content while in the background` case. You can add the `UIBackgroundModes` key in your **plist** file with the `audio` mode to enable using your app when in background.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure, that it is not possible to use speech recognition in background. Used this sample [project](https://github.com/appcoda/SpeechToTextDemo) and put ON all supported background modes. Worked only about 30 sec in background mode and that's it.

If you have found any another solution, to solve this problem, please let me know. Have to make project with background speech recognition support.